# NTP time synchronizes, still shows local time..?

Tags: firewall, ntp

I have set NTP time of Canada (0.ca.pool.ntp.org, 1.ca.pool.ntp.org, 2.ca.pool.ntp.org, as obtained from https://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/ca). The sync server IP is 192.210.199.110 (stratum 2). When I check the IP address it is from US. However, the time of the firewall is still local (GMT) and not of the Canada.

Is my understanding of NTP correct, that the firewall is suppose to have its NTP time set for Canada (meaning the time of the firewall should be same as current time in Canada)

The actual issue is that my current time is GMT +1 but the firewall still shows as GMT 0 and which got me thinking if NTP is actually working, and that it is how I understand it is.

**Firewall NTP Time and Sync Server**

[image: https://i.ibb.co/bswK2th/NTP.png]

[image: https://i.ibb.co/jb2Y26R/NTP2.png]

[image: https://i.ibb.co/t844BQP/NTP3.png]

Comment: Care to provide more info on the software you're using?

Comment: This is OPNsense Firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)

> NTP is intended to synchronize all participating computers to within a few milliseconds of **Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).**

NTP has no concept of "local" time because that would make it nearly impossible to synchronise servers in any sensible way without first knowing what offset it has from the "main" or parent source it got its time from.

If a server was moved or had its offset adjusted then that change would flow down to every server below, potentially changing the time across entire swathes of the Internet if machines depend on that time server.

Instead NTP gives all the servers the same time: UTC.

Thus way all that has to be done is to synchronise the "current" time. There are no offsets to flow down or keep track of and it is entirely up to the client to work out its own "local" time.

This is typically done via a system "timezone" setting. In Linux you can use `timedatectl` (see Linuxize [How to get or change timezone](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-or-change-timezone-in-linux/)) and in Windows you would normally use the Control Panel region or time settings to set up timezone information.

So why do we have regional NTP servers? For load balancing time requests and for overall accuracy. Sending an NTP request to the other side of the planet can have major latency from satellite links and poorly configured firewalls and the route can, in theory, change from moment to moment. If the route were static then you could at least work out the round trip time and compensate your local time that way. Out of preference you would end up making multiple requests and averaging the round trip time.

By using a more geographically local server you are hopefully reducing the round trip time, cutting down on the need for multiple time requests (reducing load on the server) and getting a more accurate reading for the true "current" time.